# SpringSecurity UserDetailsService get password

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm creating authentication service in Spring.

I'm using UserDetailsService to get form variables, but i found that loadUserByUsername has only one variable - userName.

How to get password ?

```
public class userAuthentication implements UserDetailsService{

    private @Autowired
    ASPWebServicesUtils aspWebServicesUtils;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        //how to get password ?

        User user = new User("test", "test", true, true, true, true, getAuthorities(true));

        return user;  

    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(boolean isAdmin){

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(2);
        authorityList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER_ROLE"));
        if(isAdmin){
            authorityList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN_ROLE"));
        }
        return authorityList;

    }
//...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I have webserwice, which provide informations, is user exist. I have to pass login and password to this webserwice.

Comment: You should probably read the [FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-what-is-userdetailservice) and the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#tech-userdetailsservice) on `UserDetailsService` and what it is for. It is only for loading data into the framework.

Comment: Not answering your question, but whenever you've got a constructor that takes a whole lot of random arguments, it's a sign of a builder pattern. For example: User.builder().accountExpired(false).accountLocked(false).credentialsExpired(false).roles("ROLE_USER").disabled(false).build(); is better than new User(...)

Answer (score 20):

If you look at the [User](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) object, the second parameter in the constructor is the password.

The [UserDetailsService](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) is used to load the user from a back-end structure like database. The [loadUserByUsername](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html#loadUserByUsername%28java.lang.String%29) method is called when a user tries to login with a username and password, then it is the responsibility of the service to load the user definition and return it to the security framework. The required details includes data like `username`, `password`, `accountNonExpired`, `credentialsNonExpired`, `accountNonLocked` and `authorities`.

Once the spring security receives the user object, it will validate the user against the password entered by the user and other data like user account status (accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired etc)

Comment: That i know - i'm creating it. I want to receive data passed in form.

Comment: It is the responsibility of the spring framework to handle the password, the security framework will compare the password entered by the user and the password sent from the service

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I can simply name the UserDetails password field passwd, pass, password or whatever I want, how does the authentication manager recognizes it?

Comment: Storing the raw password in the database is a very bad idea. You should only store a _hash_ of the password, i.e. with [BCryptPasswordEncoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html). Unfortunately, this can't be implemented in the UserDetailsService, because it can't access the password entered by the user.

Answer (score 17):

Some of the standard (out-of-the-box) mechanisms to retrieve the user information and provide authentication information are:

- **inMemoryAuthentication**
- **jdbcAuthentication**
- **ldapAuthentication**
- **userDetailsService**

If the above does not suit your purpose and you need to have a custom solution, you can create and configure a new authentication provider like so:

**Security Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    ....
}
```

**Authentication Provider:**

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        // You can get the password here
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        // Your custom authentication logic here
        if (name.equals("admin") && password.equals("pwd")) {
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name,
                    password);

            return auth;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: I would add a third parameter to new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, new ArrayList<>()). This way the constructor will set `isAuthenticated` to true, so you won't experience problems with access to pages restricted for authenticated users

Answer (score 3):

I believe a `UserDetailsService` is supposed to be used to acquire a `UserDetails` object from some back end storage, database, flat file, etc. Once you have that `UserDetails`, spring security (or you) have to compare it to the username (or other principals) and password (the credentials) provided by the user in order to authenticate that user.

I don't think you are using it the way it is intended.

Comment: Hi, how do I implement this password check against a database in Spring Security? Do I have to override any method or implement any interface?

Answer (score 3):

Get password in `UserDetailsService` implementation by `request.getParameter("password")`:

```
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        String password = request.getParameter("password"); // get from request parameter
        ......
    }
}
```

`RequestContextHolder` is base on `ThreadLocal`.

If your project is base on Spring Framework (not Spring Boot), add `RequestContextListener` to web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: spring boot has no web.xml

Answer (score 1):

XML Implementation:

```
<authentication-manager  alias="loginAuthenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="loginAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Bean implementing AuthenticationProvider of Spring Security -->
<beans:bean id="loginAuthenticationProvider" class="com.config.LoginAuthenticationProvider">
</beans:bean>
```

AuthenticationProvider:

```
public class LoginAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        // You can get the password here
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        // Your custom authentication logic here
        if (name.equals("admin") && password.equals("pwd")) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `loadUserByUsername(String name)` is a method defined on an interface (userServicedetails I think), which your service implements. You have to write the implementation.

Just as you have to write the implementation for getPassword() or similar ... spring does not provide that. I imagine the password is stored in your user object, but you wrote that ... did you create a `getPassword()` method ?